# Algebra of sets

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Does it follow that $$A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2) \subseteq (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2 ) $$

My thought: We know $A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2) = (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_2)$. So, pick a point $x \in (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_2)$. Hence, $x$ is either in $(A \cap E_1)$ or in $(A \cap E_2)$.

If $x \in (A \cap E_1)$, then $x$ is clearly in $(A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2 ) $

If $x \in (A \cap E_2) $, then $x \in (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2 ) \implies x \in (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2 ) $

So, it is true our problem. IS this correct way to show it? Some feedback or a better way to solve this problem would really be helpful. thanks

Comment: Alternatively, $E_1\cup E_2 = E_1\cup(E_1^c\cap E_2)$

Comment: So, actually, they are equal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my favourite approach for problems like this: start with the most complex side, so compute which elements are in $\;(A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2)\;$, by expanding the definitions and simplifying:
\begin{align}
& x \in (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand definitions of $\;\cup\;$, $\;\cap\;$, and $\;^c\;$"} \\
& (x \in A \land x \in E_1) \lor (x \in A \land \lnot(x \in E_1) \land x \in E_2) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: extract common $\;x \in A\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land (x \in E_1 \lor (\lnot(x \in E_1) \land x \in E_2)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: use negation of $\;x \in E_1\;$ in other side of $\;\lor\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land (x \in E_1 \lor (\lnot\text{false} \land x \in E_2)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \land (x \in E_1 \lor x \in E_2) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"re-introduce $\;\cup\;$ and $\;\cap\;$ using their definitions"} \\
& x \in A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2) \\
\end{align}
So (by set extensionality): yes, the two expressions from your question are actually equal.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $x\in A \cap (E_1 \cup E_2)$ and  discuss the two cases:

- If $x\in E_1$;
- otherwise $x\in E_1^c$
  using the fact
  $$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$$

Comment: But my solution is correct or not?

Comment: No your solution is wrong. To prove that $A\subset B$ you should take $x\in A$ and prove that $x\in B$ but what you wrote "So, pick a point $x \in (A \cap E_1) \cup (A \cap E_2)$..." and this is clearly wrong.

Comment: +30 for my friend Sami. :-)